# Separating raster by land use attribute in R

Tags: r, attributes, extract, raster

I am new to R and trying to extract a subset of values from a raster file. I am using the [Ontario Land Cover Compilation (OLCC) v.2.0](https://geohub.lio.gov.on.ca/documents/7aa998fdf100434da27a41f1c637382c/about) and want to only extract impervious cover values within my buffer regions. According to the [Data Specifications](https://www.sdc.gov.on.ca/sites/MNRF-PublicDocs/EN/CMID/Ontario%20Land%20Cover%20Compilation%20-%20Data%20Specification%20Version.pdf) there are classification names for land use classes and associated codes. I only want to extract data from the Community/Infrastructure name (code 27). I have uploaded the entire raster into R. Is there a way to separate the raster by code name/class? If I get the separated raster subset I know how to extract within my buffer region from there.

I have tried the raster brick function to see if it would recognize the code names and separate them into different layers automatically but this didn't work. I saw another post where raster attributes were extracted by class, but I am not sure how the land use classes are being separated and defined in R here.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some example data

```
library(terra)
#terra 1.5.6
set.seed(0)
x <- rast(nrows=10, ncols=10, names="cover")
values(x) <- sample(3, ncell(x), replace=TRUE) - 1
levels(x) <- c("forest", "water", "urban")
```

Inspect

```
x
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 10, 10, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 36, 18  (x, y)
#extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 
#source      : memory 
#name        :  cover 
#min value   : forest 
#max value   :  water 

levels(x)[[1]]
#[1] "forest" "water"  "urban" 

cats(x)[[1]]
#  ID category
#1  0   forest
#2  1    water
#3  2    urban
```

So if you were interested in extracting the "urban" areas only, you can see that the ID (cell value) for that class is 2. And you can do

```
urban <- x == 2
plot(urban)
text(x)
```

[image]
urb <- x == "urban"

It *should* also have been possible to do

```
urb <- x == "urban"
```

But that may be offset by one class in some cases. To use this safely, you need terra 1.5-7 (currently the [development version](https://github.com/rspatial/terra/))

Also, if there are multiple categories, you may first need to activate the category you are interested in; like so:

```
activeCat(x) <- "cover"
```